# "MIMEParsingException: Missing start boundary" exception happening only in Chrome Browser, Firefox works fine during Jersey fileUpload

Tags: google-chrome, file-upload, jersey, multipartform-data, mozilla

FYI, I have the following jersey jars in my app's classpath along with the mimepull jar version as:

```
jersey-apache-client-1.11.jar
jersey-apache-client4-1.11.jar
jersey-client-1.17.1.jar
jersey-core-1.17.1.jar
jersey-guice-1.17.1.jar
jersey-json-1.17.1.jar
jersey-multipart-1.17.1.jar
jersey-server-1.17.1.jar
jersey-servlet-1.11.jar
mimepull-1.6.jar
```

I even tried with all of them either 1.11 or 1.17.1 for the jersey specific jars. When I tried to submit a file upload request via my latest Chrome browser (here is the client side html code to submit the file upload):

```
<form name="uploadFile" action="/app/fileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" class="input-file"/><br/>
<button type="submit" id="upload-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Strangely enough, my file upload jersey resource is not even hit and I get a 400 error in my Chrome browser with the following exception in my server logs, however it works just fine in my Firefox browser:

```
[toResponse] WebApplicationExceptionMapper status='400' message='org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: Missing start boundary' url='/app/fileUpload'
    javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: Missing start boundary
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:146)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:82)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:488)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:552)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider$FormDataInjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider.java:122)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    ...
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:216)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:634)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:445)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: Missing start boundary
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser.skipPreamble(MIMEParser.java:306)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser.access$300(MIMEParser.java:67)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser$MIMEEventIterator.next(MIMEParser.java:143)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser$MIMEEventIterator.next(MIMEParser.java:128)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.makeProgress(MIMEMessage.java:198)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.parseAll(MIMEMessage.java:181)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.getAttachments(MIMEMessage.java:106)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:187)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:80)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:144)
        ... 46 more
```

Here is the Request payload which also looks correct when compared with Firefox payload, I dont understand why I see 400 for the same request in Chrome browser but 200OK in Firefox

```
  Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryNkIU5AivMR0pDmZG
   Host:localhost:8080
   Origin:http://localhost:8080
   Referer:http://localhost:8080/app/files
   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36
   Request Payload
   ------WebKitFormBoundaryNkIU5AivMR0pDmZG
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.zip"
   Content-Type: application/zip


   ------WebKitFormBoundaryNkIU5AivMR0pDmZG--
```

Any pointers to resolve this error will be highly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information from my side to get further insight into the issue.

Here is the Jersey resource method signature:

```
@POST
@Path("/fileUpload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadMultiPartFormData(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file_in,
@FormDataParam("file")FormDataContentDisposition fileName) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Do You have a not working example on github for instance? Ready to import and run?

Comment: I'm a geting a similar error;but in my case the problem is with the Mozilla browser and the error is "Reached EOF, but there is no closing MIME boundary". This is only happening when the file I try to upload is being used and modified by some other process. Chrome and IE are handling this case properly, but for some reason Mozilla is not able to.